# SQL - Top 10 in columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a SQL query to create the top 10 for the columns `ipAdress` and `ID` per month. The result is correct but I need the result in another format.

Can you help me to get the right format ?

My SQL query is

```
SELECT    
   MyMonth, 
   ipAddress, 
   ID ,
   Records
FROM    
(
   SELECT    
      MyMonth ,
      ipAddress, 
      ID, 
      Records,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MyMonth ORDER BY so.Records DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM   
    (
        SELECT    
            LEFT(DATENAME(month,startDate),3) + ' ''' + RIGHT(YEAR(startDate),2) AS MyMonth
            ,ipAddress, ID ,COUNT(1) AS Records
        FROM  
            [TEST_AUSWERTUNG].[dbo].[Evaluation] 
        GROUP BY 
            LEFT(DATENAME(month,startDate),3) + ' ''' + RIGHT(YEAR(startDate),2) ,ipAddress, ID
    )so
)x
WHERE x.RowNum < 11
```

And the result is for example

`Aug'14 145.998.111.115 14  191481
Aug '14 145.998.991.145 E1  81448
Aug '14 11.14.48.11     P4  44544
Aug '14 145.998.49.149  U4  95814
Aug '14 11.4.949.49     CD  94941
Aug '14 11.4.949.45     XT  99449
Aug '14 11.4.949.45     CD  91188
Aug '14 145.998.49.54   XT  91994
Aug '14 11.4.949.49     XT  91954
Aug '14 145.998.49.44   BM  91444
Jun '14 145.998.111.115 14  118494
Jun '14 145.998.991.145 E1  49915
Jun '14 11.14.48.11     P4  41114
Jun '14 145.998.49.159  XB  49414
Jun '14 145.998.49.149  U4  94449
Jun '14 145.998.49.199  XB  94148
Jun '14 11.4.949.49     CD  99154
Jun '14 11.4.949.45     XT  99154
Jun '14 145.998.49.44   XT  91449
Jun '14 145.998.49.54   XT  91554`

But i need it like this:

`Aug'14 145.998.111.115 14  191481 Jun '14  145.998.111.115 14  118494
Aug '14 145.998.991.145 E1  81448 Jun '14   145.998.991.145 E1  49915
Aug '14 11.14.48.11     P4  44544 Jun '14   11.14.48.11     P4  41114
Aug '14 145.998.49.149  U4  95814 Jun '14   145.998.49.159  XB  49414
Aug '14 11.4.949.49     CD  94941 Jun '14   145.998.49.149  U4  94449
Aug '14 11.4.949.45     XT  99449 Jun '14   145.998.49.199  XB  94148
Aug '14 11.4.949.45     CD  91188 Jun '14   11.4.949.49     CD  99154
Aug '14 145.998.49.54   XT  91994 Jun '14   11.4.949.49     CD  99154
Aug '14 11.4.949.49     XT  91954 Jun '14   11.4.949.45     XT  99154
Aug '14 145.998.49.44   BM  91444 Jun '14   145.998.49.44   XT  91449`

Anyone has a solution ?

Comment: Join `Aug` subset and `Jun` subset together on `RowNum`. Or group by `RowNum` like pivot. There are many answers about pivot you could search in this site.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have explained what you want to achieve with the query, and I'm not going to investigate it. Even so, I'll let you know how to do it:

- use a [CTE (WITH)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to use this query as if it was a table
- make two different queries of the table expression created with WITH:

  - one that takes the data from Aug'14
  - other that takes the data from Jun'14
- join both queries, ON `ipAddress` and `ID`

Something like this (pseudocode):

```
WITH T ( list of fields in your query )
AS
( your query )
SELECT 
   T1.MyMonth, T1.ipAddress, T1.ID, T1.records,
   T2.MyMonth, T2.ipAddress, T2.ID, T2.records
FROM
    (T WHERE MyMonth='Aug ''14') T1
INNER JOIN
    (T WHERE MyMonth='Jun ''14') T2
ON T1.ipAddress = T2.ipAddress and T1.ID = T2.ID
```

I'm sure that you must know what you're trying to achieve, and will be able to improve the query in some way, once you have it working.

Comment: It's just an example the month'year could be also "Jun'12" or "Jan'10". So this solution would not work :(

Comment: Yep, it's pseudocode. I don't know where you get the months from, I don't know what `startDate` is. Please, be a little proactive, and replace that with the required expression. Perhaps you have to modify the defining query of the CTE, expose other fields, use other expressions for filtering and so on. This is a guidance, not a literal solution. Work it out, please, and, if you have any problem, update your question.

Comment: Sorry but i am a rookie in sql. StartDate is a column in the database and it can be filled with every month of every year. The query should record the top10 of the combination of ipAdress and ID for every Month of every year. I hope this is usefull.